# iOS 14 - Thumbnails do not display in the UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios14

Thumbnails do not display in the UIImagePickerController when running on iPhone 11 or real device with iOS 14.

```
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate=self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Result:

Photos and Albums showing as Blank but when I tap on-screen image will be selected.

[image]

Comment: Did you ask permission to access photo's? Did you maybe said the the app only had permission to access selected photos?

Comment: @rckoenes Yes, asked permission and also shows permission popup if you want to keep the same selection or select more photos. The problem is related to photos because I'm able to select photos but can't see thumbnails as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: UIImagePickerController is deprecated. Switch to PHPickerViewController.

Comment: @matt tried PHPickerViewController getting the same issue thumbnails aren't visible.

Comment: I facing same issue have you found solution.

Comment: This is a beta. If you’re seeing issues, file a bug report immediately. Invisible view controllers, such as the color picker and the font picker, have plagued these beta releases from day one.

Comment: @matt yes this is beta but the problem is that i have created a new project and did same implementation in that and it is working fine in that project that's why I'm concerned.

Comment: @AB OK cool, but then _you_ need to tell us what's different in the one that has the problem. We're not seeing the issue, you are.

Comment: @AB Have you found the solution? I am also facing this issue with Xcode 12 and iOS 14 out of the beta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, it was caused by using

```
UIScrollView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationController.self]).backgroundColor = .backgroundPrimaryNew
```

I don't know why is that, but after I've removed this line it began working again and thumbnails are showing.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Removing the UIAppearance calls for UIScrollView fixed the problem, somehow on iOS 14 the UIImagePickerController is respecting those when it never did before, be careful!

Answer (score -3):

Try this
Instead of presenting add `UIImagePickerController` as `subView`

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate=self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

[self.view addSubview:self.picker.view];
[self addChildViewController:self.picker];
[self.picker didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```